# Illegal characters in path exception using trunkUrl in CruiceControl Config file

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

I am trying to setup the ccnet.config file and when specifying trunkUrl under sourcecontrol, it is throwing an illegal characters in path message.

Could anyone please look into the below and tell what's wrong with my trunkUrl?

```
<sourcecontrol type="svn">
  <trunkUrl>https://serverName/svn/ProjectName/branches/v2.95</trunkUrl>
  <workingDirectory>c:\source\mydirtory/workingDirectory>
  <username>david</username>
  <password>david123</password>
</sourcecontrol>
```

Comment: I suppose the URL in your sample is not exactly the same as the real one, right? Check that the real one doesn't contain spaces

Comment: Thanks. I found a hidden special character in the path and I deleted it and it all worked fine.

Comment: It would be good if you shape it as an answer so that others see the solution facing with this thread.